# Create two sqlsrv_fetch_array question one after another

Tags: php

Probably a newb question, but when I put two PHP sqlsrv_fetch_array statements, one after another, the second one never works. It just returns blank.

So if I create two simple drop down menus, calling their values from a sqlsrv_fetch_array, then I'll get all the values in the first drop down menu, but none in the second.

```
<?php 

echo "<select>";
while( $PersonRow = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $PersonDropdownArray, SQLSRV_FETCH_BOTH))  
{  
    echo "<option value=\"".$PersonRow['Person']."\">".$PersonRow['Person']."</option>";
}  
echo "</select>" ;


echo "<select>";
while( $PersonRow = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $PersonDropdownArray, SQLSRV_FETCH_BOTH ))  
{  
    echo "<option value=\"".$PersonRow['Person']."\">".$PersonRow['Person']."</option>";
}  
echo "</select>" ;
?>
```

It seems to be the case that after its run through all the values in the array the first time, it has nothing left to run through the second time, so my second drop down menu is blank. But does anyone know how to reset it, to go back to the beginning of the array for the second time I call the sqlsrv_fetch_array?

Comment: After the first loop, all rows from the statement have been retrieved.  You would either need to reposition the sql cursor(if supported), re-execute the statement or store the values in the first loop and re display them.

Comment: Ok, that's great. And how would I do any of that? I really am a newb! The easiest option sounded like repositioning the sql curser. But how would I go about storing a whole array of values in php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It seems to be the case that after its run through all the values in
> the array the first time, it has nothing left to run through the
> second time

Yes, after you fetch all of the rows there are no more.  Just fetch once and save what you need.  One way given your code:

```
$options = '';
while( $PersonRow = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $PersonDropdownArray, SQLSRV_FETCH_BOTH))  
{  
    $options .= "<option value=\"".$PersonRow['Person']."\">".$PersonRow['Person']."</option>";
}  

echo "<select>$options</select>";
echo "<select>$options</select>";
```

FYI, you'll need to give the select inputs a name to get them when submitted.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to do it:

I simply needed to reassign the query to the array I already had, by re-stating the following:

$PersonDropdownArray = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $PersonDropdownQuery);

As folllows:

```
<?php 

echo "<select>";
while( $PersonRow = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $PersonDropdownArray, SQLSRV_FETCH_BOTH))  
{  
    echo "<option value=\"".$PersonRow['Person']."\">".$PersonRow['Person']."</option>";
}  
echo "</select>" ;

$PersonDropdownArray = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $PersonDropdownQuery);    

echo "<select>";
while( $PersonRow = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $PersonDropdownArray, SQLSRV_FETCH_BOTH ))  
{  
    echo "<option value=\"".$PersonRow['Person']."\">".$PersonRow['Person']."</option>";
}  
echo "</select>" ;
?>
```

Comment: No, don't query multiple times.

Comment: How else should I do it?